# Docusign JWT authentication with ionic3

Tags: webpack, ionic3, docusignapi

I am trying to implement Docusign JWT authentication to a ionic3 app by following https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/code-example-embedded-signing

Here is what I did in a page:

```
import { DocuSign } from 'docusign-esign';

...

export class Page {
    async ngOnInit() {
        const tokenReplaceMin = 10, // The accessToken must expire at least this number of
            jwtLifeSec = 10 * 60, // requested lifetime for the JWT is 10 min
            scopes = "signature";

        let dsApi = this.docusign.ApiClient();

        dsApi.setOAuthBasePath('https://account-d.docusign.com');
        const results = await dsApi.requestJWTUserToken(this.client_id, this.impersonatedUserGuid, scopes, this.privateKey, jwtLifeSec);

        const expiresAt = moment().add(results.body.expires_in, 's').subtract(tokenReplaceMin, 'm');
        
        this.dsAccessToken = results.body.access_token;
        this.dsTokenExpiration = expiresAt;
       
        return {
           accessToken: results.body.access_token,
           tokenExpirationTimestamp: expiresAt
        };
    }
}
```

Once the server launched, I have got the following error:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot find module "Configuration" ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Cannot find module "Configuration"
    webpackMissingModule index.js:14
    617 index.js:14
    617 index.js:19
    Webpack 27
```

The debugger is highlighting this line https://github.com/docusign/docusign-node-client/blob/master/src/index.js#L14

I presume that is an importation issue with webpack.

Answer (score 0):

Ionic is defined on their [website](https://ionicframework.com/docs):

> ... for building performant, high-quality mobile and desktop apps

That means that you should not be using JWT grant since the secret (or key) can't be protected on mobile or desktop apps.

You should be using [Implicit Grant](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-implicit) instead.